# How to add microphone access to containers for multiple clients?

Tags: sound, firefox, microphone, docker, container

I’m running into a frustrating problem. I installed an ubuntu version 20.04 and installed Docker on it
I started a container named linuxserver/firefox on Docker.
I tried to set up the microphone for users who use this image, but unfortunately I could not do this.
Is there a way to add microphone access to this image?
thanks a lot